# Correct place to put extra startup code in django?

Tags: python, django

I would like to run some environment checks when my django process starts and die noisily in the case of an error. I'm thinking things like the database has an incorrect encoding or the machine has a python version we don't support.

I'd rather our team be faced with a fatal error that they have to fix, rather than be able to ignore it.

I'm Ok with writing these checks but  I'm curious about where the best place to put them is. How do I get them to execute as part of django's startup process? I thought there might be a signal I could listen too, but I can't find a relevant one in the docs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put them in settings.py. In the past, I have put system checks like this:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print "Missing %s" % os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "local_settings.py")

if DEBUG:
    for p in [PROJECT_ROOT, MEDIA_ROOT, THEME_DIR, ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT] + list(TEMPLATE_DIRS):
        p = os.path.normpath(p)
        if not os.path.exists(p):
            print "Missing path: %s" % p
```

Comment: I can see that it'd work, however mixing executable code and configuration feels "wrong".

Comment: SUre, I'll buy that. PiotrLegnica's suggestion of \_\_init\_\_.py sounds good, although I doubt you'll get the initialization done in settings.py done at the time it is loaded.

Comment: `settings.py` would be my choice, too, for this safety check. i thought there was a post-model-validation signal (the kind of model validation optionally done by a management command), but i couldn't find one in the source.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use settings module, then try project's `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check that the system is correctly installed, I think that you should write your [own admin command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it as post-installation check.

I think that it doesn't worth to check if the python version is correctly installed too often especially if you are installing the django app on shared-host. My app is hosted at alwaysdata and they restart the FastCgi process every hour. These checks can have an impact on the application response time.

Answer (score 4):

We use the top-level `urls.py` for this.

Comment: I have moved my question to your later answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only

Answer (score 3):

I have tested all three __init__.py Settings.py and urls.py methods and this is what I have found.

When code is run from either __init__.py or Settings.py, the start up functions are run **twice** upon web server start up; when the start up functions are run from urls.py the code is run **once**, however it is run only upon the first request made to the we server leading to a potentially long wait for the first user to visit your site.

It is standard practise to call a 'warming' page when bringing large web applications back online so I don't see that calling a start up function from a CLEARLY identified location in the urls.py should be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers here are extremely old, so I assume that's why [Django's checks framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/checks/) isn't mentioned.

It's been a part of django since at least v2 (django==3.1 at the time of writing).

That's probably the right place for most of the checks you're requiring.

I'd still consider using `settings`, as mentioned by other answers, for checks where `settings` contents are required but which also need to be run prior to readying the apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in settings.py as mentioned by others, but having code in the settings is not ideal. There is also the option of adding a handler for django.db.models.signals.class_prepared that does the desired start up checks after a specific model class is prepared.