# Customized django manage.py use case

Tags: python, django, orm

I am actually using `django` only to use its *Object relational mapper(ORM)* feature and, currently, have nothing to do with its web-framework. At present I have successfully been able to customize `django.setting` to suit my database needs and defined some test data `models` but bumped into `manage.py`, which is required to build the database tables etc.

How can I call `manage.py`(or achieve its very purpose) from within the module where the `model` is defined and not from the command line?

Comment: Just being curious, why don't you use [SQLalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html) if its only an ORM you're after?

Comment: @Hedde Good point, actually while I was asking the question a colleague of mine suggested it to me. Looking into it.

Comment: @IvanKharlamov the question is, where am i supposed to plant those pieces of code?

Comment: It depends on your application's logic. :)

Comment: @IvanKharlamov no i mean to ask should it be planted where the model is actually defined or some place else?

Comment: It could be planted anywhere in your python scripts. `models.py` is probably not the best choice, though. But, first of all, you should answer the question: **"but why the hell do I need it?"**. It looks like you really don't need django and should go with `SQLalchemy` instead. @Hedde should probably create an answer to this question which you, IMHO, should definitely accept.

Comment: @IvanKharlamov if it can be planted anywhere how would it detect amongst 10-20 modules/packages which ones contains has a `model` defined? To answer your other concern, it is highly unlikely that I'll be using it. But that doesn't answer the question. Or does it?

Comment: Django project has a [predefined structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/), so that syncdb in the scope of the project will affect only the apps which are a part of `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: @IvanKharlamov i suggest you combine your 1st and last comment into answer which I will accept because it worked. Hedde's comment was a really apt suggestion but not an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Hedde is probably right about [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html) being a better suit, but if you still want to programmatically access `manage.py` commands, checkout answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495964/in-django-how-do-i-call-the-subcommand-syncdb-from-the-initialization-script).

Django project has a [predefined structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/), so that `syncdb` in the scope of the project will affect only the apps which are a part of `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file.

The really fun stuff is that you can even have [on-the-fly schema alteration](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant) with `django-mutant`. *Of course, you should use it only when you're absolutely sure about when and what you're doing :)))*.