# Django: Applying database migration on server start with wsgi

Tags: python, django

I would like Django to automatically apply migrations when server starts.
How to do it?

I serve django with uwsgi - actually as one of emperor applications.

After publishing new version, I change wsgi.ini file and emperor restarts whole service. But database is not migrated.

But when running tests - locally - by manage.py the migrations are apllied to the database.

Currently the only idea I have is to call subprocess.check_output("manage.py migrate") from settings.py.

The problem here is that calling system command is dependent on system environment. Additionally wsgi is usually running on virtual env.

I could be missing something but is must be possible to run migrations from within the starting code of server.

Comment: Have you tried: `python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file wsgi.py which is generated next to settings.py add:

`from django.core.management import call_command`

and after setup call migrate:

`application = get_wsgi_application()
call_command("migrate")`

related answers:
[In django, how do I call the subcommand 'syncdb' from the initialization script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495964/in-django-how-do-i-call-the-subcommand-syncdb-from-the-initialization-script)

Comment: This solutions works, should be accepted