# Where to Disconnect() the `default_product_search_listener` in Satchmo

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I don't want to use the Default Satchmo search listener. I've created my own search listener instead.

Where is the best place to disconnect the default search listener?

```
# This is what I need to do...
from satchmo_store.shop.listeners import default_product_search_listener
application_search.disconnect(default_product_search_listener, sender=Product)
```

I was trying to do it in my app's `__init__.py` and the my app's `models.py`, but both of those seemed to run ***before*** Satchmo actually `connect`s the Signal, so they don't properly disconnect things. Where can I run my disconnect code so that I can be assured Satchmo has already connected its listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is more generally answered by [Where To Put Django Startup Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code).

> Write middleware that does this in **init** and afterwards raise django.core.exceptions.MiddlewareNotUsed from the **init**, django will remove it for all requests...

See the Django [documentation on writing your own middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware).

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the order of Satchmo and your app in INSTALLED_APPS.