# Function running in background all the time (and startup itself) in Django app

Tags: python, django, background-process, startup

I create simple Django app. Inside this app I have single checkbox. I save this checkbox state to database if it's checked in database I have `True` value if checkbox is uncecked I have `False` value. There is no problem with this part. Now I created function that prints for me every 10 second all the time this checkbox state value from database.

Function I put into views.py file and it looks like:

```
def get_value():
    while True:
        value_change = TurnOnOff.objects.first()
        if value_change.turnOnOff:
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
        time.sleep(10)
```

The point is that function should work all the time. For example If I in `models.py` code `checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=False)` after I run command `python manage.py runserver` it should give me output like:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 04, 2019 - 09:19:47
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'CMS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
true
true
true
true
```

then if I visit website and change state is should print false this is obvious. But as you notice problem is how start this method. It should work all the time even if I don't visit the website yet. And this part confuse me. How to do this properly ?

I need to admit that I tried some solutions

- put this function at the end of manage.py file,
- put this function into `def ready(self)`,
- create middleware class and put method here (example code below).

**But this solutions doesn't work.**

middleware class :

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        get_value()
```

Comment: You can run a peroidic task in task queue like celery there you can put your function. check this http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using the [`AppConfig.ready()` hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) and combining it with a sub-process/thread.

Here is an example `apps.py` file (based on the tutorial `Polls` app):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django import db



class TurnOnOffMonitor(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        # This import needs to be delayed. It needs to happen after apps are
        # loaded so we put it into the method here (it won't work as top-level
        # import)
        from .models import TurnOnOff

        # Because this is a subprocess, we must ensure that we get new
        # connections dedicated to this process to avoid interfering with the
        # main connections. Closing any existing connection *should* ensure
        # this.
        db.connections.close_all()

        # We can do an endless loop here because we flagged the process as
        # being a "daemon". This ensures it will exit when the parent exists
        while True:
            value_change = TurnOnOff.objects.first()
            if value_change.turnOnOff:
                print("true")
            else:
                print("false")
            time.sleep(10)


class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
    def ready(self):
        monitor = TurnOnOffMonitor()
        monitor.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is the thing that best suits your needs from what you've described.

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a single or more worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet, or gevent. Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or synchronously (wait until ready).

You need to create task, run it [periodically](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), [call](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) if you want to manually trigger is (in some view/controller).

NOTE: do not use `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: @KyluAce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439650/how-to-run-arbitrary-code-after-django-is-fully-loaded you just call your task when your django app is started.

Comment: as I wrote in questinon method `ready()` doesn't work.  But anyway I create this celler task using this tutorial http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html  put this to startup in __init__.py file and this doesn't work. I gives me `AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` error like in previous solutions