# How to call a function after ALL Django apps have started

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to load a number of classes I've put in a module that's not part of the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` list. (I want my customers to be able to write their own subclasses which can be dynamically loaded or reloaded.) I have a function called `load_classes()` to do so. The question is where to call it when my project initially starts.

My first attempt at this was placing `load_classes` in the `ready()` function of `AppConfig` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439650/how-to-run-arbitrary-code-after-django-is-fully-loaded), but that apparently only is invoked after the particular app with the `AppConfig` is done loading, not all of them. Since these class definitions import models and functions from other apps in the project, I ended up with this error:

```
File "/Users/dylan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipeproj-oDyHbVBN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Where can I place my importing code, so it's triggered **once all of the Django apps have been loaded**?

Comment: Did you write `import` at the top of the file, or in the `ready` function?

Comment: I'm using `importlib.import_module` within the `ready` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willem Van Onsem's comment prodded me to look at my entire `apps.py` file where I call the `ready` function. Though I was using `importlib.import_module` for the dynamic loading, I had another totally separate `import` at the top of the file that drew upon other apps. Once I took that out I got past the error.

So the lesson is, contain all dependencies on other apps to within the `AppConfig.ready` call. Thanks, Willem!

Answer (score 2):

after some time trying to figure out how to do this, I came up with the following:

```py
def wait_for_ready_event(ready_event):
    print('wait_for_event starting')
    event_is_set = ready_event.wait()

    try:
        # code
    except Exception as e:
        _thread.interrupt_main()

    print('event set: %s', event_is_set)

t1 = threading.Thread(name='model_validator',
                      target=wait_for_ready_event,
                      args=(apps.ready_event,))
t1.start()
```

if you lode this code in at any point in the app, it will wait for the main thread to send out the `ready_event` signal, and then your new thread can run its code