# Django filter JSONField when key is a number

Tags: django

`node_status` is JOSNField, how to filter node_status has `{'2': True}` of queryset.

```
>>> instance.node_status
{'cat': '1', '2': True, 'dog': True}
>>> qs.filter(node_status__cat='1')
Yeah got result
>>> qs.filter(node_status__has_key='dog')
Yeah got result
>>> qs.filter(node_status__2=True)
<QuerySet []>
```

node_status__2=True got empty queryset.

```py
#models.py
from django.db import models
class Foo(models.Model):
    node_status = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)

instance = Foo.objects.create(node_status={'cat': '1', '2': True, 'dog': True})
qs = Foo.objects.all()
qs.filter(node_status__cat='1')
qs.filter(node_status__has_key='dog')
qs.filter(node_status__2=True)
```

Envrioment:

```
MariaDB 10.2
Django  4.0.1
```

Comment: Can you add `Model` example code and how you insert `{'cat': '1', '2': True, 'dog': True}` data? Current question is understandable but hard to reproduce

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically converting number-like values to numbers and array indexes:

Let's compare raw `SQL`s

```py
print(Foo.objects.filter(node_status__has_key='dog').query)
print(Foo.objects.filter(node_status__has_key='2').query)
```

```
SELECT `django4_foo`.`id`, `django4_foo`.`node_status` FROM `django4_foo` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(`django4_foo`.`node_status`, 'one', $."dog")
SELECT `django4_foo`.`id`, `django4_foo`.`node_status` FROM `django4_foo` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(`django4_foo`.`node_status`, 'one', $[2])
```

As you can see `2` is converted to `$[2]` but `dog` is converted to `$."dog"`

One possible solution is to get raw SQL, reformat it manually and init new query set using raw SQL:

```py
raw_sql = str(Foo.objects.filter(node_status__has_key='2').query).replace(f'$[2]', f'\'$.2\'')

print(raw_sql)

rqs = Foo.objects.raw(raw_sql)

for o in rqs:
  print(o.node_status)
```

```
SELECT `django4_foo`.`id`, `django4_foo`.`node_status` FROM `django4_foo` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(`django4_foo`.`node_status`, 'one', '$.2')
{'cat': '1', '2': True, 'dog': True}
```

However this hack don't work with `node_status__2=True` filter.

Let's check this query for `dog` key:

```py
print(Foo.objects.filter(node_status__dog=True).query)
```

Output is:

```
SELECT `django4_foo`.`id`, `django4_foo`.`node_status` FROM `django4_foo` WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`django4_foo`.`node_status`, $."dog")) = JSON_EXTRACT(true, '$')
```

But actually working raw SQL is:

```
SELECT `django4_foo`.`id`, `django4_foo`.`node_status` FROM `django4_foo` WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`django4_foo`.`node_status`, "$.dog")) = 'True'
```

So here is many problems with `filter` → `raw` conversions. (**Django community also don't recommend to use `str(query)` for raw SQL query generations**)

Django is positioned like universal screwdriver for all types of screws. Internal conflicts and overcomplicated "universal and all in one" logic is a common problem for Django.

Yes it is possible to override `query` class and [change key transformation logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571827/13946204) but it is hard to read and understand, pretty complicated and another problems may occur with customized logic (because Django don't expect that logic was changed).

So easier ways will be:

- just use `Foo.objects.raw(sql_query)` where `sql_query` is predefined manually string
- use [`cursor.execute(sql_query, \[params\])`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) with `sql_query` predefined same as ①
- get `Foo.objects.all()` and use python logic to filter it (`[e for e in Foo.objects.all() if '2' in e.node_status]`)

Other possible ways are:

- [Integrate `sqlalchemy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606725/best-way-to-integrate-sqlalchemy-into-a-django-project)
- Migrate to another framework ([FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/), etc) ※

※ My choice ;)