# Running startup code right after Django settings? (also for commands)

Tags: django, settings, signals

I am using `mongoengine` and would like to run `connect()` after settings (not inside them [as suggested in its docs](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.5/django.html)). This is actually more like a general question how to run code right after all settings are loaded.

Update: I need a solution for management commands as well. Common approach is adding a middleware with exception `MiddlewareNotUsed` or adding code to root urls.py, but both don't work for commands.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code

Comment: @ustun, if you could make your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Take a look at the following question, it should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code

Comment: I just did, but it automatically converted the answer to a comment, with the following message: "Trivial answer converted to comment" :)

Comment: Hm, it is a nice solution, but I still have the issue for management commands. I would be nice to have something more universal.

Comment: @ustun: That's because posting a link to another SO question is not an answer in and of itself. If the question can be answered that easily, then it's most likely a dupe and should be closed. (in this case, the OP is technically wanting something additional that the other question doesn't cover, which is the only reason I haven't voted to close it.)

Comment: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only says the opposite of the answer linked by ustun: do not use a weird middleware but put it in the urls.py :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal place for startup-like code is in a urls.py (when you need the settings to be already loaded). Django doesn't have a good spot yet for this.

(There is an "app refactor" branch that a gsoc student worked on in 2011, but it didn't get merged into core django yet. This "app refactor" includes a solution to your very problem, but that doesn't help you...)

You mention that a management command also needs it. Is that your own management command? Nothing stops you from importing the urls.py there, is it?

This *is* sadly one of the few Django weak points. Luckily there aren't that many :-)