# Run startup code in the parent with Django and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, hook, startup, gunicorn

I need my code run at Django application startup, before Django starts listening for incoming connections. Running my code upon the first HTTP request is not good enough. When I use Gunicorn, my code must run in the parent process, before it forks.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781488/97248 doesn't seem to work in Django 1.4.2: it doesn't run the Middleware's `__init__` method until the first request is received. Ditto for adding code to `urls.py`.

A quick Google search didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: Is there something in the Django site you need to run, or are you forking off daemon processes or something?

Comment: Forking daemons is dangerous - you can make nephilim that way :/

Comment: I want to run some quick checks before the site can go live. I won't spawn any daemons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old but in Gunicorn version 19.0 and above, you can create a [custom script](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/custom.html) to run your application and include the startup code that you need there. Here is an example script using a django app:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Script for running Gunicorn using our WSGI application
"""

import multiprocessing

from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication

from myapp.wsgi import application  # Must be imported first


class StandaloneApplication(BaseApplication):
    """Our Gunicorn application."""

    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {
            key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
            if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None
        }
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gunicorn_options = {
        'bind': '0.0.0.0:8080',
        'workers': (multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2) + 1,
    }

    # Your startup code here

    StandaloneApplication(application, gunicorn_options).run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just run into this problem myself, and the solution was to basically chain the commands to guarantee execution and correct order:

Script started by systemd, supervisord or any other such system:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py my_custom_command && gunicorn project.wsgi $@
```

Create your own custom django command and off you go. You can get some speedups if you disable sanity checks in the command [(`requires_system_checks` and `requires_migrations_checks` set to `False`)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/#attributes).

To make things more generic, you could create a "boot" signal to which you connect arbitrary functions, and just emit the signal from this custom command.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this workaround. However, I can't accept it as an answer, because the `python manage.py` environment can be substantially different from the `gunicorn project.wsgi` environment, and I want to run my checks in the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn allows you to specify a variety of [hooks](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#server-hooks), including `on_starting` and `pre_fork`, either of which sound like what you might want.

How to use: suppose you have the module `my_app.startup_stuff` that contains the following code you want to run:

```
def some_prefork_tasks(server):
  print('I\'m running pre-fork')
```

Create a `gunicorn.conf.py` file in the directory where you run gunicorn with the following contents:

```
from my_app import startup_stuff

pre_fork = startup_stuff.some_prefork_tasks
```

Then when you run gunicorn, it should print "I'm running pre-fork".

(gunicorn.conf.py is loaded automatically if it exists, but you can call the config file whatever and load it with `-c <config>`. See [the docs on config files](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#configuration-file) for more info.)