# entry point hook for django using gunicorn_django

Tags: django, startup, gunicorn

I'm using Django 1.4.1 with the gunicorn and nginx on my server with a setup similar to [Django-Nginx-Gunicorn](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/).

What I need is a good place to hook into Django, so that I can initialize stuff like signal listeners on startup (so it works with all management commands and server startup).

I am aware that a lot of people use urls.py or the middleware hack ([Where to put Django startup code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code)), but those don't seem to get called when I run `python manage.py shell`. And at some point down the road a startup signal will be available, but I don't want to fork Django to include it, unless absolutely necessary.

I really like the startup script technique from [Entry Point Hook Django Projects](http://eldarion.com/blog/2013/02/14/entry-point-hook-django-projects/) and it works correctly when using `python manage.py runserver` or any other management command. However, gunicorn starts Django without calling the management command and I can't figure out where I would modify my gunicorn startup script to run the startup.py, as shown in the WSGI.py example. Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know about a single place that would work for both gunicorn and management commands. I have such initialization related stuff in wsgi.py, but this one isn't called by management commands. Maybe you could put it in wsgi.py and manage.py?

Comment: gunicorn doesn't call the wsgi that apache does, it has it's own internal stuff. I ended up putting it in both manage.py and urls.py, and checking a boolean to see if the code already ran.