# Executing code on startup in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

It seems Django allows to execute the code on startup - when the app starts, however, it's not clear and where I should put the code. So how can I execute the code on startup in Django 1.7?

Comment: What do you mean by "startup"? When what starts exactly?

Comment: @rnevius, the application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Django>=1.7 you can use the `AppConfig.ready()` callback:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

For previous versions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781488/2011147).

If you are using the `AppConfig.ready()` method:

1) Create a `myapp/apps.py` module and subclass the AppConfig. For example:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    def ready(self):
    ...
```

2) Edit `myapp/__init__.py` and register your app config:

```
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#configuring-applications for details.