# Redefinition of AppConfig.ready()

Tags: django, django-signals

Django 1.9.

Trying to learn signals. In the documentation for AppConfig.ready() it is said that "Subclasses can override this method to perform initialization tasks such as registering signals." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready).

**some_app/apps.py**

```
class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'some_app'

    def ready(self):
        print("Redefined ready method in some_app")
```

**demo_signals/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "some_app.apps.SomeAppConfig",
]

python manage.py runserver
Redefined ready method in some_app
Redefined ready method in some_app
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 25, 2016 - 15:15:58
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'demo_signals.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Please, note that "Redefined ready method in some_app" is printed twice.

Could you help me understand why it is called twice. And this is not my mistake, why two calls are necessary for registering signals?

Comment: Probably the dev server is starting up two separate threads. What happens if you start it with `--nothreading`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, tried. Again twice.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I've just started a completely new project. Twice again. Nothreading doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Popen run twice when using it under if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324052/why-does-popen-run-twice-when-using-it-under-if-name-main)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you use `python manage.py runserver` Django start two processes, one for the actual development server and other to reload your application when the code change

You can test it importing `os` inside your `AppConfig` class and print the process id inside the `ready` function like so:

```
import os

class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'some_app'

    def ready(self):
        print(os.getpid())
```

You will see it prints two different processes

You can also start the server without the reload option, and you will see only one process running (and your code `print("Redefined ready method in some_app")` will only be executed once):

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```