# How to serialize queryset in get method in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement calculation logic in APIView class following [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786308/django-and-rest-api-to-serve-calculation-based-requests).
However, I got below error because I tried to serialize queryset, not dictionary as demonstrated in the page.
Does anyone know how I can pass queryset to serializer as argument? If not, are there any way to convert into format which can be serialized by serializer?

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got QuerySet."
    ]
}
```

**views.py**

```
class envelopeData(APIView):

    def get(self,request,pk):
        #pk=self.kwargs['pk']
        #print (pk)

        glass_json=self.get_serialized(pk,"glass")
        print (glass_json)

    def get_serialized(self,pk,keyword):
        queryset = summary.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=keyword)
        serializer = summarySerializer(data=queryset) <=get error here
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        data=serializer.validated_data
        return data["json"]
```

**serializer.py**

```
class strToJson(serializers.CharField):

    def to_representation(self,value):
        x=JSON.loads(value)
        return x

class summarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project=serializers.CharField(read_only=True,source="html.project")
    version = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="html.version")
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source="html.pk")
    json = strToJson()
    #json=serializers.JSONField(binary=True)

    class Meta:
        model=summary
        fields=('pk','project','version','json')
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be aware of  these things,

1. Since you are passing a **`QuerySet`** object, you ***must not*** provide the **`data`** argument.
2. **`QuerySet`** is a ***`list` like object***, so you should provide **`many=True`** while serialization.
3. the **`is_valid()`** method only is applicable only if you pass a dictionary to the **`data`** argument, which is not here.

So, change you **`get_serialized()`** method as,

```
def get_serialized(self, pk, keyword):
    queryset = summary.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=keyword)
    serializer = summarySerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = serializer.data
    return data["json"]
```

**References**

1. [Dealing with multiple objects in Serializer ---- **`many=True`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)
2. [**`is_valid()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#using-is_validraise_exceptiontrue)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can see you need to provide serializer class with `many=True`.
As for docs:

> To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object
>   instance, you should pass the many=True flag when instantiating the
>   serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be
>   serialized.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects

So the line that raises error should look this way

```
serializer = summarySerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Implementing many=True, I got error below                  {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"."
    ]
}

Comment: @KatsuyaObara Could you try `serializer = summarySerializer(queryset, many=True)`? Mind there is no `data` parameter name.

Comment: I tried serializer = summarySerializer(data=queryset, many=True) but result is same.  { "non_field_errors": [ "Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"." ] }