# start-stop-daemon spawning 2 processes

Tags: python, django, unix, debian

trying to make my django site as service. Here is the code:

```
DIR=/home/karonator/pk-akr
DAEMON=$DIR/manage.py

DAEMON_NAME=somename
DAEMON_OPTS="runserver 0.0.0.0:7777"

DAEMON_USER=karonator

PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"

    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --exec /usr/bin/python $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    log_end_msg $?
```

}

This works but start-stop-daemon spawning two processes:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it? As the result the stop  and restart functions not works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--noreload` to `DAEMON_OPTS="runserver 0.0.0.0:7777"`

Here is a link explaining `--noreload` and the auto-reloader process.

[Why is run called twice in the Django dev server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489863/why-is-run-called-twice-in-the-django-dev-server)