# [django]A lib need load a file on init, how to reuse this lib in django views without init twice?

Tags: python, django

I am using a lib to get user location by their IPs.
main code:

```
...

datfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "ipdb.dat")

class IPv4Database(object):
    def __init__(self, filename=None, use_mmap=True):
        print 'IPv4Database init'
        if filename is None:
            filename = datfile
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            if use_mmap and mmap is not None:

        ...
```

I know read a file would cost a lot,so I want `ipdb = IPv4Database()` just call once, then use `ipdb` in the whole django project. 
First thing I thougnt is to set `ipdb` as a globla variable,but the only way I know is puting `ipdb = IPv4Database()` to `settings`.Is it Ok to initiate a object in settings?

Another way ---- cache :
Save the file to cache seems not good, `__init__` still need to load this file.
So as `pickle`, `pickle ipdb` and save to cache, then unpickle every time I need it.I afraid it is not good if the file is large.

What should I do?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable in your module.

e.g.

in the file appname/ipdb.py

```
ipdb = IPv4Database()

...
```

Then where you need it you can do

```
from appname.ipdb import ipdb

... do something with ipdb
```

Just make sure you absolutely only need a single instance of you Ip database.

Comment: This is is good for Django < 1.7. Django 1.7 and above have [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig)

Comment: True, with app config it is more flexible for the site(s) using it and you do not need to depend directly on this module when using it somewhere else.