# how to create an entry in the database on start django

Tags: python, django

I have an app with

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and I want that when it is being started with `python manage.py runserver` that the it checks if the name 'Hemingway' is already created and if not it should be created. What's the best way of doing that? 
I know how to do it manually over the shell or how to create it in with forms `Author.object.create(name='Hemingway')`. So, for example if I flush the database and restart my app, the name Hemingway will be created.

And in which file would that be done ?

Comment: You should not try to do this via the ORM, but [like so](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/). There may or may not be automatic loading available depending on your version of Django, but note they list this behavior as deprecated.

Comment: ahh initial data, that's the term is was looking for, thanks!

Comment: tell me if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Two-Bit Alchemist one way is through [Providing initial data with fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/).

This means creating a fixtures folder with a `yourfilename.json` file. 
Then with `python manage.py loaddata yourfilename` the data gets loaded into the database.

In the example above the json file should look like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "visitors.author",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Hemingway"
    }
  }
]
```