# In Django, how can I prevent my signals import in AppConfig.ready() from running more than once?

Tags: python, django, signals, django-signals

To keep signals organised:

`__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'posts.apps.PostsConfig'
```

`apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'posts'

    def ready(self):
        import posts.signals
```

How do I ensure that `ready()` or `import posts.signals` only runs once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform model operations (only once) at server init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341793/perform-model-operations-only-once-at-server-init)

Comment: What problems are you encountering when `ready()` runs twice? Importing the signals twice should not cause any problems.

Comment: @solarissmoke your edit to the answer on there is what I'm looking for, thanks. The context of the question is different - that's a request for help fixing an error, this is a best-practice question based on the docs. Not fussed if it's closed, but I couldn't find your answer on that other question before I posted this.

Comment: @knbk No issue yet, just wanted to know how to account for it as the documentation says I should without an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'posts'
    ready_has_run = False

    def ready(self):
        if self.ready_has_run:
            return
        import posts.signals
        self.ready_has_run = True
```