# Running code on Django application start

Tags: python, django

I need to run some code every time my application starts. I need to be able to manipulate models, just like I would in actual view code. Specifically, I am trying to hack built-in User model to support longer usernames, so my code is like this

```
def username_length_hack(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    model = sender._meta.model
    model._meta.get_field("username").max_length = 254
```

But I cannot seem to find the right place to do it. I tried adding a class_prepared signal handler in either models.py or app.py of the app that uses User model (expecting that User will by loaded by the time this apps models are loaded). The post_migrate and pre_migrate only run on migrate command. Adding code into settings.py seems weird and besides nothing is loaded at that point anyway. So far, the only thing that worked was connecting it to a pre_init signal and having it run every time a User instance is spawned. But that seems like a resource drain. I am using Django 1.8. How can I run this on every app load?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only) might help you.

Comment: *I am trying to hack built-in User model* <= This is where I stopped, because [you can much easier provide a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). It's even documented how to change the username field. Monkey patching the model is not a good idea.

Comment: @dhke I cannot convert a multi-megabyte codebase to a custom user model.

Comment: @Harrison I will try the middleware approach

Comment: @MadWombat Not if it's referencing `contrib.auth.models.User` everywhere, yes *sigh*.

Comment: Yeah, it is using old school "user profile" approach

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments; there are prettier approaches than this.

You could add your code to the `__init__.py`of your app

Comment: Models are not loaded by the time `__init__.py` is parsed