# Threading database issues in celery tasks using eventlet

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

I have a project under dev VM 'ubuntu/trusty'.
I use **virtualenv** with the following packages:

```
celery 3.1.23
eventlet 0.18.4
django 1.8.15
mysqlclient 1.3.9
```

Python version is 3.4.3.
MySql version is 5.5.

I use **supervisor** with **eventlet** as a worker for run some services and **celery** tasks among them. This is the part of the supervisor's configuration:

```
[program:celery-worker-default]
command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/python /vagrant/meridian/meridian/manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue
directory=/vagrant/meridian/meridian
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery-worker-default-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery-worker-default-stderr.log
priority=999
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=5
```

When tasks are running they fail with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 231, in trace_task
    loader_task_init(uuid, task)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 114, in on_task_init
    self.close_database()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 85, in close_database
    return self._close_database()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 76, in _close_database
    close()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 64, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 403, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 191, in close
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 421, in validate_thread_sharing
    % (self.alias, self._thread_ident, thread.get_ident()))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 140089123953704 and this is thread id 140088751748512.
```

Any task that contains DB operations fails.

I tried to use **select_for_update()** and **with atomic():** in the task bodies, but without any success.

Also I searched in the Net about that issue, but have found no solution.

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: I use mysql db and python package mysqlcleint 1.3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer. The issue was that I used to run celery under the **manage.py** managment script:

```
[program:celery-worker-default]
command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/python /vagrant/meridian/meridian/manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue
```

I have rewritten that line in this way:

```
[program:celery-worker-default]
command=bash -c "/vagrant/meridian/meridian/start_default_queue.sh"
```

And this the content of **start_default_queue.sh**:

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/activate
workon meridian
exec celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue
```

I don't know why, but running **celery worker** directly have fixed that mysterious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find something like `on_load` hook for Celery and put the following code there:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(MySQLdb=True)
```

It has to be executed before any Django code.

Comment: I added these two lines to the **manage.py** of my project, but unfortunately without any success. Any ideas where I should add these lines ?

Comment: Also I tried to add this to configuration file, but it wasn't work.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16111968/73957 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

or Celery `app.on_init()` http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#laziness

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and was able to fix it by adding

`numprocs = 1`

to the supervisord configuration for my celery service. In your example this could look like this:

```
[program:celery-worker-default]
command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/python /vagrant/meridian/meridian/manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet -c 3 -Q default -E -n default.queue
directory=/vagrant/meridian/meridian
numprocs = 1
…
```

It's not really clear to me why this changes anything though, because a value of 1 should also be the default.