# Is there a way to hook a script into Django's test server, so that it executes on each reload?

Tags: python, django, server

I have certain files that I want to be static on production but want to be able to write dynamically during development. So I would like to be able to execute a script to accomplish this each time the test server reloads, so that changes I have made will be taken into account, and the file gets updated. Is there any way to hook into the autoreloader to do this, or is this something I would need to do manually?

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to your `settings.py` which gets loaded on the devserver reload.

```
# settings.py
# ...
if DEBUG:
    import your_function
    result = your_function()
    print(result)
```

Comment: Clever suggestion, and it would work if I didn't need access to models, which don't load until after the settings file. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only). In short, I just added the following to the end of urls.py.

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    my_dev_reload_script()
```

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073606/thomas-schw%C3%A4rzl) was close, but placing this in settings makes app references impossible. Putting it in urls ensures that apps are loaded.

Comment: Indeed, didn't thought of that in first place.