# Removing items from celery_beat doesn't remove them from database schedule

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I'm using `django-celery-beat` in a django app (this stores the schedule in the database instead of a local file).  I've configured my schedule via `celery_beat` that Celery is initialized with via `app.config_from_object(...)`

I recently renamed/removed a few tasks and restarted the app.  The new tasks showed up, but the tasks removed from the `celery_beat` dictionary didn't get removed from the database.

Is this expected workflow -- requiring manual removal of tasks from the database?  Is there a workaround to automatically reconcile the schedule at Django startup?

I tried a `PeriodicTask.objects.all().delete()` in `celery/__init__.py`

```
def _clean_schedule():                                                         
    from django.db import transaction                                           
    from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask                          
    from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTasks                         
    with transaction.atomic():                                                  
         PeriodicTask.objects.\                                                  
            exclude(task__startswith='celery.').\                               
            exclude(name__in=settings.CELERY_CONFIG.celery_beat.keys()).\      
            delete()                                                            
         PeriodicTasks.update_changed()                                          
_clean_schedule()
```

but that is not allowed because Django isn't properly started up yet:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

You also can't use Django's `AppConfig.ready()` because making queries / db connections in `ready()` is not supported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689002/8060120

Comment: @BearBrown I'll try that.  I've tried AppConfig.ready() and making DB connections is unsupported.  Wsgi is worth a try.

Comment: wsgi or manage if you run the develop

Comment: @BearBrown I found an even better way -- which is to hook into django celery's mechanism for installing `beat_schedule`.  Answer is below.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at how `django-celery-beat` actually works to install the schedules, I thought I maybe I could hook into that process.

It doesn't happen when Django starts -- it happens when *beat* starts.  It calls `setup_schedule()` against the class passed on the beat command line.

Therefore, we can just override the scheduler with

```
--scheduler=myproject.lib.scheduler:DatabaseSchedulerWithCleanup
```

to do cleanup:

```
import logging

from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask                               
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTasks                              
from django_celery_beat.schedulers import DatabaseScheduler                     
from django.db import transaction                                                


class DatabaseSchedulerWithCleanup(DatabaseScheduler):                           

    def setup_schedule(self):                                                    
        schedule = self.app.conf.beat_schedule                                   
        with transaction.atomic():                                               
            num, info = PeriodicTask.objects.\                                   
                exclude(task__startswith='celery.').\                            
                exclude(name__in=schedule.keys()).\                              
                delete()                                                         
            logging.info("Removed %d obsolete periodic tasks.", num)            
            if num > 0:                                                          
                PeriodicTasks.update_changed()                                   
        super(DatabaseSchedulerWithCleanup, self).setup_schedule()
```

Note, you only want this if you are *exclusively* managing tasks with `beat_schedule`.  If you add tasks via Django admin or programatically, they will also be deleted.