# Google Cloud Profiler showning [Unknown - No Python thread state]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-profiler

Today I started using [Google Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler) for a Python3 project running on Google App Engine Standard Environment.

I expected to see references to my functions in the resulting flame graph, I spot only a `[Unknown - No Python thread state]` in CPU time profile.

I followed [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python#standard-environment).

I don't understand if this is the expected result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling the profiler start function? The profile start function should be called once and as early as possible. If you already haven't move the profile initialization code to Django's urls.py file see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only) post. Then load test your app.

If you are using uWSGI, there are some limitations you need to be aware about which is mentioned in the Profiler [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python#limitations)

Comment: Hello @MaryM, it's a Flask app, the profiler start function call is at the very top of my module `__init__.py`. Executed before it there's only `main.py` which is a simply `from my_module import app`