# Python's sqlite3 library sometimes returns naive datetimes and sometimes aware datetimes for the same column

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime

I have a `TIMESTAMP` column in my SQLite database storing a datetime with a timezone, e.g. `2021-09-29 18:46:02.098000+00:00`. When I fetch this row inside my Django app, the column is returned as an [aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) datetime object. However, when I fetch this row in a script that doesn't use Django, in the exact same code path, the column is returned as a naive object.

Note that in both cases I am using the built-in `sqlite3` library, not Django's ORM.

Why are the return types inconsistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django ships with a built-in [SQLite converter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types) for `TIMESTAMP` columns that overrides the [built-in Python converter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters), and, unlike the built-in one, return aware datetimes if the database column contains a time zone.

Since the converter is registered globally, it applies regardless of whether you are using the Django ORM or not.

To override Django's converter, you can call `sqlite3.register_converter` in the [`ready` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/) of one of your apps, e.g.:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "myapp"

    def ready(self):
        sqlite3.register_converter("TIMESTAMP", my_converter)
```

Python's sqlite3 doesn't expose its naive timestamp converter as a public method, but it is short enough that you can copy-paste it from [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/sqlite3/dbapi2.py#L66).

Alternatively, you can register a time zone-aware converter in your non-Django code, e.g. using [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

The converter is registered in the Django codebase [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L77), and the original ticket with some discussion is available [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17755).

Comment: I wonder why the built-in converter doesn't attempt to use `datetime.fromisoformat` - which would set the UTC offset and return aware datetime

Comment: Perhaps it is simply an oversight, given that `datetime.fromisoformat` was only added in Python 3.7. I filed a bug against CPython: https://bugs.python.org/issue45335

Comment: Well, for legacy code <3.7 I'd expect that people are handling their UTC offsets (*time zones* is another story) in some way - which, if it expects naive datetime input, might break if aware datetime is returned after an update. So this might be more complicated than I thought at first. Updates to the standard lib should avoid breaking changes I guess, so this was a design flaw in the first place if you ask me.